# Flutter and widget updates

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I have the following state of a statefull widget

```dart
class _ParkingMapState extends State<ParkingMap> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final position = Provider.of<Position?>(context);
    CameraPosition cameraPosition = (position != null) ? CameraPosition(
        target: LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude), zoom: 14.0) : const CameraPosition(
        target: LatLng(34.345, 34.345), zoom: 14.0);
    return GoogleMap(
            initialCameraPosition: cameraPosition,
          );
  }
}
```

position is a Future of `Position` from the `geolocator` library that is resolved through a future provider. I want to be able to load the map with a random position if for some reason `position` wasn't able to resolve and with the user's current position if the Future is resolved. My problem is that maps widget in my case get's renderred normally in the random position (since initially position is null) and it doesn't update.
Updating my return value to

```dart
return (position != null) ? GoogleMap(...) : const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
```

I get the desired result, and map renders the current position in the map once `position` has been resolved. Could you explain the mechanics a bit so that I can understand why this is hapenning?

Comment: Your problem is not widget update. when you have a change of the position, just call a google maps function that updates the position of the camera; for example: GoogleMap.of(_key).moveCameraBounds(bounds);

Comment: Could you provide with some sample code?